# Probability and Statistical Modelling Proof (Negative Binomial into Poisson)

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

The Negative Binomial RV $X$ models the number of trials until the $r$-th success in a sequence of independent Bernoulli Trials with probability of success $p$ in each trial. So, if $q = 1 - p$,

$$P(X = k)= \begin{pmatrix} k-1 \\r-1 \end{pmatrix}p^rq^{k-r},k=r,r+1,\dots.$$

Let $Y = X - r$.

Suppose that $r\to\infty$ and $q\to 0$ so that $rq\to\lambda$.

Show that, for fixed $m=0,1,\dots$

$$P(Y=m)\longrightarrow\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}e^{-\lambda}.$$

---

So what I did so far was

Let $r=\frac{\lambda}{q}$,with $q\to 0$

Then $P(Y=m) = P(X=r+m)$

So I got

$$P(X = r+m)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\lambda}{q}+m-1\\ \frac{\lambda}{q}-1 \end{pmatrix} p^{\frac{\lambda}{q}}q^{m}, m=0,1,\dots.$$

and I don't know what to do next, can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the limit as $q\rightarrow 0,$ but express the last line as
$$P(X=r+m)=\frac{(\frac{\lambda }{q}+m-1)!}{m!(\frac{\lambda }{q}-1)!}(1+\frac{1}{-1/q})^{-\lambda /q}q^m\frac{r^m}{r^m}=\underbrace{\frac{(\frac{\lambda }{q}+m-1)!}{r^m(\frac{\lambda }{q}-1)!}}_{\rightarrow 1}\underbrace{(1+\frac{1}{-1/q})^{-\lambda /q}}_{\rightarrow \color{red}{e^{-\lambda}}}\color{red}{\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}}$$ use that $rq=\lambda ,$ use the known limit $(1+1/x)^x\longrightarrow e$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$  and use that 
$$\frac{(r+m-1)!}{r^m(r-1)!}=\frac{r^{\overline{m}}}{r^m}\longrightarrow 1,$$ the las line i would use the expansion in Stirling numbers of the raising factorial but i guess is just an argument of the degree of the polnomial in $r.$

Comment: What does $\bar{m}$ mean?

Comment: @user:290189 means $r(r+1)\dots (r+m-1)$ is the Raising factorial.

Comment: @JadenCheong Sorry for confusion. I did not mean $r^m/r^m$ but $r^{\overline{m}}/r^m$ which is $((r+m-1)(r+m-2)\dots (r+1)r)/r^m$ It is called the raising factorial(check wikipedia) and i used to cancel the $(r-1)!$ in the denominator.

Comment: right. so the denominator of m! stays but $\frac{\frac{\lambda}{q}+m-1)!}{\frac{r^m(\frac{lambda}{q}-1)!}$ becomes 1

Comment: @JadenCheong In the limit, yes. I edited a little.

Comment: can you clarify where the $\lambda^m$ came from please ? Also in the first line, is it $\frac{r^\bar{m}}{r^m}$ ?

Comment: @JadenCheong The first line is $r^m/r^m$ i multiply by one to be able to get in the numerator $q^mr^m=(\lambda)^m$

Comment: Thank you, I get it now